# .ics file showing correct time in Google Calendar but +1 hour in Outlook

Tags: outlook, calendar, icalendar

I'm working on a community platform that offers the option to "Add to calendar" events that a user signs up for. There are several options under the "Add to calendar" button, one being the iCal where a .ics file is downloaded.
The .ics file imported into Google Calendar, opened on my iPhone, shows the right time.
But when I directly open the .ics file on my computer (Windows 10), it systematically shows the time with +1 hour.

Do you know if an extra line of code should be added for Outlook to read the file correctly? Are there any lines of code missing?
I see the "DAYLIGHT" component, but not the "STANDARD" or the "RRULE". Should they be there?

For reference this meeting should take place on Wednesday 28 June 2023 at 9:00 am CEST.

Many thanks,
Emma

Here is the full code I see when I open up the .cs file with Notepad:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:3f1381ff81df578f0e9a7c23995cd515
SUMMARY:XYZ introductory webinar - June 2023, session 1
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Europe/Zurich
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:20230628T100000
TZNAME:CEST
TZOFFSETTO:+0200
TZOFFSETFROM:+0200
END:DAYLIGHT
END:VTIMEZONE

DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20230628T090000
DTEND;TZID=Europe/Zurich:20230628T100000
DESCRIPTION:Event link: https://testURL
Welcome to XYZ!

We are very excited to have launched this new community platform and look forward to showing you around XYZ and explaining where you can find things. There will also be a Q&amp;A session at the end.

Click ENROLL and add this webinar to your calendar!

** We are running 2 sessions on June 28th, the content of the sessions will be the same, choose the one that suits you best. **
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```